# Example of doing search on supercolumns in cassandra using thrift library

Tags: cassandra, thrift

Say if I wanted to do a search in cassandra:

```
keyspace: "blog-app"
super-col-family: "user"
row-key: <this is what I want> 
scol-key: "data" 
col-key: "name"
col-value: "Bob"
```

How is this done. (I want to use a SlicePredicate to do this)

Comment: What did you try? Remember, this is SO.

Comment: I read the thrift documentation and got a couple of links to source code in python. It is very poorly documented